# How to validate radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I created the following form:
http://jsfiddle.net/baumdexterous/GYNSu/1/

I implemented a validation script that works for many of the form elements but for some reason it's not working for the radio buttons so currently a user can submit the form without selecting one of the required radio buttons.

How can I enable validation for the radio buttons using this existing script? Thanks so much.

```
    <ul>
        <li class="required">
            <label>What is the U.S. Capital? Please select your answer below:</label>
            <div class="questionsone">
                <input name="questionone" type="radio" value="a">a) New York<br>
                <input name="questionone" type="radio" value="b">b) Washington DC<br>
                <input name="questionone" type="radio" value="c">c) Seattle<br>
                <input name="questionone" type="radio" value="d">d) Portland<br>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**Update**: I have this JavaScript part that works with the existing validation. Trying to figure out how to add a way that will detect radio buttons:

```
    <script>
      $(function() {
          var root = $("#wizard").scrollable();
          // some variables that we need
          var api = root.scrollable(),
              drawer = $("#drawer");
          // validation logic is done inside the onBeforeSeek callback
          api.onBeforeSeek(function(event, i) {
              // we are going 1 step backwards so no need for validation
              if (api.getIndex() < i) {
                  // 1. get current page
                  var page = root.find(".page").eq(api.getIndex()),
                      // 2. .. and all required fields inside the page
                      inputs = page.find(".required :input").removeClass("error"),
                      // 3. .. which are empty
                      empty = inputs.filter(function() {
                          return $(this).val().replace(/\s*/g, '') == '';
                      });
                  // if there are empty fields, then
                  if (empty.length) {
                      // slide down the drawer
                      drawer.slideDown(function() {
                          // colored flash effect
                          drawer.css("backgroundColor", "#229");
                          setTimeout(function() {
                              drawer.css("backgroundColor", "#fff");
                          }, 1000);
                      });
                      // add a CSS class name "error" for empty & required fields
                      empty.addClass("error");
                      // cancel seeking of the scrollable by returning false
                      return false;
                      // everything is good
                  } else {
                      // hide the drawer
                      drawer.slideUp();
                  }
              }
              // update status bar
              $("#status li").removeClass("active").eq(i).addClass("active");
          });
          // if tab is pressed on the next button seek to next page
          root.find("button.next").keydown(function(e) {
              if (e.keyCode == 9) {
                  // seeks to next tab by executing our validation routine
                  api.next();
                  e.preventDefault();
              }
          });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: You should keep the names the same for those radio buttons, otherwise you can select all of them at once. Keeping the name the same ensures that at most one of the radio buttons can be checked.

Answer (score 1):

Have the radio button names all be the same. That groups them together. Then all you have to do is make the first one have `checked="true"`

```
<input name="question" type="radio" value="a" checked="true">a) New York<br>
<input name="question" type="radio" value="b">b) Washington DC<br>
<input name="question" type="radio" value="c">c) Seattle<br>
<input name="question" type="radio" value="d">d) Portland<br>
```

This makes them send at least one thing. Otherwise you have to check the selected value of the input.

Also all the text inputs could just have `required` attribute and that would make sure something is there. HTML5 has that as validation.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

**EDIT**
Here's a fiddle I just made using jQuery. This is the true validation you want.
http://jsfiddle.net/slyfox13/H9Dw2/

Comment: I like the idea of auto checking at least one of the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Your radios should all have the same name. In the code about, you literally have 4 different inputs each as their own form data param, not 4 radio inputs affecting one form data param.

Answer (score 0):

The input names not all need to be the same, i.e.  and then check that the value of questionone is not null to validate

Comment: If the names aren't all the same you can select all of them, which might not be the correct use case according to the context he provided.

Answer (score 0):

Set same name to all radio buttons since Radio buttons are there for a single choice.

```
    <input name="questionone" type="radio" value="a">a) New York<br>
    <input name="questionone" type="radio" value="b">b) Washington DC<br>
    <input name="questionone" type="radio" value="c">c) Seattle<br>
    <input name="questionone" type="radio" value="d">d) Portland<br>
```

Validation using jQuery:

```
if($("input[type=radio,name=questionone]:checked").length >0)
{    
  /* do something */
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Jenson – but how do I get the existing validation (see fiddle) to appear?

Comment: @Ori I'm on mobile device, fiddle is not getting loaded right now..:(

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change your radio buttons names to all be the same thing. ex

```
<ul>
    <li class="required">
        <label>What is the U.S. Capital? Please select your answer below:</label>
        <div class="questionsone">
            <input name="question" type="radio" value="a">a) New York<br>
            <input name="question" type="radio" value="b">b) Washington DC<br>
            <input name="question" type="radio" value="c">c) Seattle<br>
            <input name="question" type="radio" value="d">d) Portland<br>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So that you will only be able to select one. Next you need to create a document.ready() function. Add this code to your document.ready()

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    function RadioTest(){
    inputs = document.getElementsByName('question');
            for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
                if(inputs[index].checked!=true){
                                alert("radio not selected");
                                    return false;
                        }
            }

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you – I tried implementing your code into my fiddle but it doesn't seem to fix it. Any thoughts?

Comment: I forgot to change name="questionon"  to name="question". I made the changes to the code you should try it now

Answer (score 0):

You have to give same name for all radio input tag.
like this

```
<div class="questionsone">
            <input name="qstn1" type="radio" value="a">a) New York<br>
            <input name="qstn1" type="radio" value="b">b) Washington DC<br>
            <input name="qstn1" type="radio" value="c">c) Seattle<br>
            <input name="qstn1" type="radio" value="d">d) Portland<br>
     </div>
```